# How to calculate duration between two time using datatables?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, datatables

Currently, I already retrieve some data from a database using data tables, for example, the entered time and left time. But, I want to calculate the duration between these two time. Seems this time is in their format, so it can't be calculated, right? Below are the codes. If you noticed, I already try to subtract the left with the entered time but, it's not working at all. Or should I make the calculation at the backend of python/Django?

```
$(function () {
    var currentDate = new Date()
    var day = currentDate.getDate()
    var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1
    var year = currentDate.getFullYear()
    var d = day + "-" + month + "-" + year;

    // Datatables intialisation
    jQdtRpt = $('#dtBasicExample').DataTable({
        columns: [
            {title: "Tag", data: "tag.name"},
            {title: "Name", data: "tag.alternate_name"},
            {title: "Station", data: "station.name"},
            {title: "Entered Time", data: "entered", render:function(data){ return moment(data).format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mm:ss a'); }},
            {title: "Left Time", data: "left", render:function(data){ return moment(data).format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mm:ss a'); }},
            {title: "Duration", data: "left - entered", render:function(data){ return moment(data).format('h:mm:ss'); }},
        ],
        dom: 'lfrtipB<"clear">',
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'copy',
                exportOptions: {
                    format: {
                        header: dtBtnExpOptFmtHdr
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                extend: 'csv',
                title: 'report_user_history_' + d,
                exportOptions: {
                    format: {
                        header: dtBtnExpOptFmtHdr
                    }
                }
            }
        ],

    });
    $('.dataTables_length').addClass('bs-select');
    // End: Datatables intialisation
});
```

Comment: you would have to convert strings to `Date()` objects - ie. `Date("2020.01.02")`

Comment: If you could provide an example, perhaps in JSFiddle, then we could probably help more. I know that moment.js has a Duration, and Diff might be used to parse both dates and create such a duration. Hope that helps a little: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/diffing/